# Zero Vector Returned error

Tags: matlab, while-loop, ode

I am building a robot simulation which solves differential equations at different input speed values, the function uses `[0 0 0]=[x y theta]` as initial conditions then updates the initial conditions every iteration.

When I use a for loop to input the number of iterations I want the equation to be solved for, it works fine! However, when I use a while loop to keep the function solving as I input the speed (through an edit text in my GUI) I get an error message

> KPATH returns a vector of length 0, but the length of initial conditions vector is 3.

How can function return a zero length vector? Or is the while loop the issue in this case ?

**code**

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global sld1
global sld2 
check = get(handles.checkbox1,'Value');
initials = zeros(1,3); %start at origin
p = par();
tspan = [0 1];
while check == true
    p.WL = sld1 ;p.WR = sld2; 
    sol= ode23(@Kpath, tspan, initials,[],p);
    [t,s] = ode23(@Kpath, tspan, initials,[],p);
    initials = deval(sol,2);
    xlabel('x-position [m]');ylabel('y-position [m]');
    title('robot path');
    grid on 
    plot(s(:,1),s(:,2),'b','linewidth',1.5);
    hold on 

end
function p = par()
         p.L = 0.12;                        %length [m]
         p.r = 0.1;                         %radius of wheel [m]
function dt = Kpath(t,c,p)
          x = c(1);y = c(2);th = c(3);
          dx = (((p.r*p.WL)+(p.r*p.WR))/2) * cos(th);
          dy = (((p.r*p.WL)+(p.r*p.WR))/2) * sin(th);
          dth= ((p.r*p.WL)-(p.r*p.WR))/p.L;
          dt = [dx;dy;dth]
```

Comment: Are you sure `check` is a boolean scalar?

Comment: yeah its a check box either a true or false